# Private list returns new List if null

Tags: c#, list

I have a class of objects I am trying to write a method that will return a list of those objects. The class has the following properties

```
private string make { get; set; }
private List<string> colours { get; set;}
private List<string> trims { get; set; }
```

Here is the method I am using to set up the list of Cars

```
public static List<Car> getCarLot()
    {
        List<Car> carLot = new List<Car>();
        List<string> makeList = getMakes(); // returns a list of strings
        List<string> trimList = getTrims(); // returns a list of strings
        List<string> colorList = getColors(); // returns a list of strings

        foreach (string m in makeList)
        {
            Car car = new Car();
            car.colours = new List<string>(); // Want to remove this
            car.trims = new List<string>();
            car.make = m;
            foreach (string c in colorList)
                car.colours.Add(c);

            foreach (string t in trimList)
                car.trims.Add(t);

            carLot.Add(car);
        }

        return carLot;
    }
```

How do I set it up so I do not have to set colours and trims to a new list of strings each time I create the object

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your properties in constructor of `Car` class:

```
public Car()
{
    colours = new List<string>();
    trims = new List<string>();
}
```

Or you can use property initializers (C# 6 or later)

```
private List<string> colours { get; set; } = new List<string>();
private List<string> trims { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

Keep in mind that in C# we use PascalCase for properties and methods names. Also it's very strange that all your class properties are private. I believe it's typo in your question. Usually properties are public.

---

And last point - if you'll use LINQ, you can simplify your `getCarLot` method a lot (even properties initialization is not required in this case):

```
public static List<Car> getCarLot()
{
    var trimList = getTrims();
    var colorList = getColors();

    var carLot = from m in getMakes()
                 select new Car {
                    colours = colorList.ToList(),
                    trims = trimList.ToList(),
                    make = m
                 };

    return carLot.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the constructor of your class:

```
public class Car
{
    private string make { get; set; }
    private List<string> colours { get; set;}
    private List<string> trims { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        colours = new List<string>();
        trims = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Or if you are using C# 6 (i.e. Visual Studio 2015) you can initialise properties directly:

```
public class Car
{
    private string make { get; set; }
    private List<string> colours { get; set;} = new List<string>();
    private List<string> trims { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Also, you can simplify you code significantly without having to change your class at all:

```
public static List<Car> getCarLot()
{
    return makeList.Select(m => new Car
    {
        make = m,
        colours = colourList.ToList(),
        trims = trimList.ToList()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using auto-properties, you have several choices:

- In C# 6 you can use property initializers
- Prior to C# 6 you need to set properties in the constructor
- You can combine list construction with populating it

I would use the third option, like this:

```
car.colours = colorList.ToList();
car.trims = trimList.ToList();
```

This makes both `foreach` loops and constructor calls unnecessary, because `ToList()` constructs and returns a copy in a single call.